# $|f(b)-f(a)|\leq g(b)-g(a)$

Tags: real-analysis

let a,b real numbers such that $a<b$ and $f$,$g$ continuos on $[a,b]$ and differntiable on $]a,b[$

suppoose that: for $x \in ]a,b[$

$ |f'(x)|\leq g'(x)$

i have proved that $g+f$ is increasing on  $[a,b]$

i have to prove that $|f(b)-f(a)|\leq g(b)-g(a)$

$*$case $1$ :  suppose that $|f(b)-f(a)| =f(a)-f(b)$

then by the monotonicity of $f+g$

$g(a)+f(a)\leq g(b)+f(b)$ then the result immediatly follows

please help me with the case$2$ when $|f(b)-f(a)| =f(b)-f(a)$

Comment: $g-f$ is also increasing (why?!)

Answer (score 5):

From $-g'(x) \le f'(x)  \le g(x)$ it follows that both $g-f$ and $g+f$ are increasing, so in addition to
$$
 g(a)+f(a) \le g(b) + f(b)
$$
you also have
$$
 g(a)-f(a) \le g(b) - f(b)
$$
and therefore
$$
 -(g(b)-g(a)) \le f(b)-f(a) \le g(b)-g(a)
$$
i.e.
$$ 
|f(b)-f(a) |\le g(b)-g(a)
$$

Answer (score 3):

We know if $f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable in $[a,b] then

$$ \mid \int_a^b f'(x)dx \mid \leq \int_a^b \mid f'(x)\mid dx$$
Given $|f'(x)|\leq g'(x)$
Hence
$$ \mid \int_a^b f'(x)dx \mid \leq \int_a^b \mid f'(x)\mid dx<\int_a^bg'(x)dx$$
$$\Rightarrow |f(b)-f(a)|\leq g(b)-g(a)$$

Comment: Note that the fundamental theorem of calculus requires a bit more than just differentiability (a continuous or at least integrable derivative).